# Communicating between controllers using service and promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm deciding a right way to communicate between controllers. There are a lot of communications happening in my app between controllers. I read that I can use either `$broadcast` or `$emit` on `$rootScope` to do this. However, I came up with another idea of using promises and a service to notify controllers.

```
<html ng-app="testApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('testApp', [])
                .service('NotificationService', function ($q) {
                    var notificationDefer = $q.defer();

                    this.whenDoSth = function () {
                        return notificationDefer.promise;
                    };

                    this.notifyOthers = function (valueToPass) {
                        notificationDefer.notify(valueToPass);
                    };

                    return this;
                })
                .controller('PubController', function ($scope, NotificationService) {
                    $scope.doSthOnClickAndNotifyOthers = function () {
                        NotificationService.notifyOthers("valueToPass");
                        // do sth else
                    };
                })
                .controller('SubController', function (NotificationService) {
                    NotificationService.whenDoSth().then(null, null, function(value) {
                        // do sth with the value
                    })
                });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="PubController as pubCtrl">
    <button ng-click="pubCtrl.doSthOnClickAndNotifyOthers()">Place Order</button>
</body>
```

Do you think this is a better approach than using $rootScope?

Comment: There is nothing intrinsically wrong with any of them. Check out Facebook's Flux patter also.

Comment: Maybe this question will be better in the code review section

Answer (score 0):

First of all yes you are right, using a service is considered a better approach then using events on the $rootScope. It is not considered a best practice to use the $rootScope because in short its quite similar to using the window object in JavaScript. So every direct interaction with the $rootScope needs to be checked if its really needed.

To go a bit further you need to think what your application wants to do and why it needs communication between controllers. Often such communication is not needed if you choose a good architecture. If two of your controllers are based on the same data set then you do not really need manual communication in AngularJS. Instead you can manage your data set in a service and both controllers can use this service to interact with the data.

If you come to the conclusion that $broadcast or $emit is better for your use case it is a valid approach. But you don't need to use these methods on the $rootScope. Often communication just needs to travel to parent or child elements in your application. In this case you can call these methods on a $scope of a single controller. $emit transmits the events upwards in the hierarchy to all parents, $broadcast the opposite way to all childs. Therefor $rootScope often is not needed even if you want to do event emitting.